# Svelte conditional slot in custom component

Tags: svelte

I am wrapping a flowbite custom svelte component called `Input` that has a slot for `left` and `right`. How can I wrap that and still pass those slots? This is what I have which works, but it's a lot IMO.. Maybe there is a cleaner way?

```
<div>
  {#if $$slots.left}
    <Input {disabled} {name} {placeholder} {type}>
      <slot slot="left">
        <slot name="left" />
      </slot>
    </Input>
  {:else}
    <Input {disabled} {name} {placeholder} {type}/>
  {/if}
</div>
```

---

Ideal usage

```html
<MyInput>
  <Icon slot="left"/>
</MyInput>
```